# IntegrityError UNIQUE constraint failed: POSTing to Django REST API, OneToOne Field

Tags: python, angular, django-rest-framework

I'm posting to a backend Django REST API using a webapp developed in Angular 7 as front end. Basically I have a supertype model `Factura` for two subtypes, `FacturaA` and `FacturaE`, they are both related by a OneToOneField.

The models in question look like this:

```
class Factura(models.Model):
    fecha = models.DateField()
    contrato = models.ForeignKey(Contrato, related_name='facturas', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pagado = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return 'Factura %s: %s - %s' % (self.id, self.fecha, self.contrato)

class FacturaE(models.Model):
    factura = models.OneToOneField(
        Factura,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    kwh = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    monto = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #calcula el monto
        if self._state.adding is True:
            self.monto = float(self.kwh) * 4.0588
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Factura Electrica'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Facturas Electricas'

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Electricidad: %s - %s' % (self.factura, self.monto)
```

In my frontend app, I POST by first creating a supertype object `Factura`, and then using the added key to post a `FacturaE` like so:

```
  addFactura(fecha: Date, kwh: number, monto: number) {
    this.factura = new Factura(0, fecha, false, this.id);
    this.pagoService.addFactura(this.factura).subscribe(f => {
      this.facturaElectrica = new FacturaEAdd(f.id, kwh, monto);
      this.pagoService.addFacturaElectrica(this.facturaElectrica).subscribe();
    });
  }
```

Adding a `Factura` followed by a `FacturaE` manually in the Django Admin produces no error, however doing this manually through the API or through my frontend app gives me the following error.

`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: CasadelaAPI_facturae.factura_id`.

Despite this error, and despite returning a 500 HTTP Status Code, the object is still created regardless of the method I use. I would like to know what's causing the error and how to fix it.

### Edit:

Solved, `super` being called twice in `save()` method overwrite, backend was trying to save the FacturaE object twice, the second `super().save(*args, **kwargs)` was producing the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you are violating `OneOnOne` attribute by creating a `FactoraE` with an existing `Factora` object assigned to it.

So the code is throwing `Unique constraint failed ...`.

Please check below steps:

- be sure that you are not trying to create another `FactoraE` with a `Factora` object that already another `FactoraE` is existed with same `Factora` Item.
- maybe in your UI code, in service (which is not provided here) you are not passing `Factora.id` correctly, so it is the same as previous requests, causing this error.

**Update**
Calling `super` two times is not recommended and it may causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the help but this is not the case. When a FacturaE gets an already  used Factura object assigned to it, the error reads as the first image posted above and prevents the creation of the FacturaE object, however when POSTing with a newly created Factura object that has not yet been used or assigned, the second error is showing but the object is still being created and shows up in the UI and in Django/admin.

Comment: please update your post and add `pagoService` from your UI

Comment: And one more thing, Why you are calling `super` two times in your `save` method. One in enough. I'm not sure but check it, maybe that is the cause of error.

Comment: You got it, calling super twice was causing the error. Thank you

Comment: anytime my friend:)